# SpringBoot Logging - Stacktrace in every log statement

Tags: java, spring-boot, slf4j

I have been developing an emailing service in **SpringBoot** and for logging I am using **slf4j**. The application is working as expected, except for the logging part. While running it on my machine the logging is working perfectly. But once it is deployed on a server, the logging work as expected until an exception occurs. After that each log statement is printed with a "stacktrace" element in it. The stacktrace is from the last exception that occurred and doesn't change until the next exception. It doesn't matter if the level of log statement is **INFO**, **WARN** or **ERROR**. It has been quite frustrating since I am not able to reproduce it and neither I have any idea what is causing this issue. I have searched google and stackoverflow but no luck. I am unable to find any posts related to this issue. Following are a few of the logging setting I am using in my application along with log statements.

Logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
<property name="PROJECT_ID" value="email-service-consumer"/>
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<encoder>
<charset>UTF-8</charset>
<Pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>${CATALINA_HOME}/logs/${PROJECT_ID}_debug.log</file>
<append>true</append>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<!-- daily rollover. Make sure the path matches the one in the file element or else
the rollover logs are placed in the working directory. -->
<fileNamePattern>${CATALINA_HOME}/logs/${PROJECT_ID}_debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

<timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
<maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
</timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
<!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
<maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>

<encoder>
<charset>UTF-8</charset>
<pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="SPLUNK_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
<file>${CATALINA_HOME}/logs/${PROJECT_ID}_splunk.log</file>
<append>true</append>
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<!-- daily rollover. Make sure the path matches the one in the file element or else
the rollover logs are placed in the working directory. -->
<fileNamePattern>${CATALINA_HOME}/logs/${PROJECT_ID}_splunk.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>

<timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
<maxFileSize>5MB</maxFileSize>
</timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
<!-- keep 30 days' worth of history -->
<maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>

<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
<charset>UTF-8</charset>
<layout class="com.example.core.logging.CcSplunkLogLayout" />
</encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="ASYNC_DEFAULTS" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
<queueSize>500</queueSize>
<discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold>
<appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
<appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
<appender-ref ref="SPLUNK_FILE"/>
</appender>

<springProfile name="!production">
<logger name="com.example" additivity="false" level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="ASYNC_DEFAULTS"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false" level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="ASYNC_DEFAULTS"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false" level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="ASYNC_DEFAULTS"/>
</logger>
<root level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="ASYNC_DEFAULTS"/>
</root>
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="production">
<logger name="com.example" additivity="false" level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="SPLUNK_FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false" level="ERROR">
<appender-ref ref="SPLUNK_FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false" level="ERROR">
<appender-ref ref="SPLUNK_FILE"/>
</logger>
<root level="ERROR">
<appender-ref ref="SPLUNK_FILE"/>
</root>
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="docker-dev">
<logger name="com.example" additivity="false" level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="SPLUNK_FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.hibernate" additivity="false" level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.springframework" additivity="false" level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
<root level="TRACE">
<appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
</springProfile>
</configuration>
```

I also wrote a util Logging class, which contains wrapper methods for different log levels.

```
public class LoggingUtil {


    public static void logWarn(String message, EmailRequest emailRequest, Logger logger) {
        Map<String, String> identifierMap = getRequestIdentifiers(emailRequest);
        StringBuffer warnMessage = new StringBuffer(checkPunctuation(message));
        warnMessage.append(Constants.REQUEST_IDENTIFIERS);

        logger.warn(warnMessage.toString(), identifierMap.get(Constants.ORDERID),
                identifierMap.get(Constants.TEMPLATENAME),
                identifierMap.get(Constants.SESSIONID),
                identifierMap.get(Constants.STOREID));
    }

    /**
     * Method to log error messages.
     * @param message
     * @param emailRequest
     * @param
     */
    public static void logInfo(String message, EmailRequest emailRequest, Logger logger) {
        Map<String, String> identifierMap = getRequestIdentifiers(emailRequest);
        StringBuffer infoMessage = new StringBuffer(checkPunctuation(message));

        infoMessage.append(Constants.REQUEST_IDENTIFIERS);

        logger.info(infoMessage.toString(), identifierMap.get(Constants.ORDERID),
                identifierMap.get(Constants.TEMPLATENAME),
                identifierMap.get(Constants.SESSIONID),
                identifierMap.get(Constants.STOREID));
    }

    public static void logInfo(String message, KafkaMessage kafkaMessage, Logger logger) {
        String sessionId = null;
        String clientOriginationId = null;
        String eventId = null;
        String eventName = null;
        String timeStamp = null;

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(checkPunctuation(message));
        stringBuilder.append(Constants.KAFKA_MESSAGE_IDENTIFIERS);

        if(kafkaMessage != null && kafkaMessage.getHeader() != null) {
            Header header = kafkaMessage.getHeader();
            sessionId = header.getSessionId();
            clientOriginationId = header.getClientOriginationId();
            eventId = header.getEventId();
            eventName = header.getEventName();
            timeStamp = header.getTimestamp();
        }

        logger.info(stringBuilder.toString(), sessionId, clientOriginationId, eventId, eventName, timeStamp);
    }

    /**
     * Method to log error messages.
     * @param message
     * @param emailRequest
     * @param e
     */
    public static void logError(String message, EmailRequest emailRequest, Exception e, Logger logger) {
        Map<String, String> identifierMap = getRequestIdentifiers(emailRequest);

        StringBuffer errorMessage = new StringBuffer(checkPunctuation(message));
        errorMessage.append(Constants.REQUEST_IDENTIFIERS);

        logger.error(errorMessage.toString(), identifierMap.get(Constants.ORDERID),
                identifierMap.get(Constants.TEMPLATENAME),
                identifierMap.get(Constants.SESSIONID),
                identifierMap.get(Constants.STOREID), e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    /**
     * This method extracts the request identfiers from email request object
     * @param emailRequest
     * @return
     */
    private static Map<String, String> getRequestIdentifiers(EmailRequest emailRequest) {
        String templateName = emailRequest != null ? emailRequest.getTemplateName() : null;
        String orderId = null;
        String sessionId = null;
        String storeId = null;
        if(emailRequest != null && emailRequest.getEmailVars() != null && emailRequest.getEmailVars().getTemplateVarsList() != null) {
            EmailVars emailVars = emailRequest.getEmailVars();
            orderId = emailVars.getTemplateVariable(Constants.ORDERID);
            sessionId = emailVars.getTemplateVariable(Constants.SESSIONID);
            storeId = emailVars.getTemplateVariable(Constants.STOREID);
        }
        Map<String, String> identifierMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        identifierMap.put(Constants.TEMPLATENAME, templateName);
        identifierMap.put(Constants.ORDERID, orderId);
        identifierMap.put(Constants.SESSIONID, sessionId);
        identifierMap.put(Constants.STOREID, storeId);

        return identifierMap;
    }

    /**
     * Method to add '.' to the message
     * @param message
     * @return
     */
    private static String checkPunctuation(String message) {
        if(message == null || message.length() == 0 || message.trim().length() == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        //Removing any trailing white spaces
        message = message.trim();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(message);

        //checking if the message ends with a period '.'
        if(message.charAt(message.length() - 1) != '.') {
            stringBuilder.append(". ");
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Log statment:

> 2018-10-31 11:45:33.770000 -0700 LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
>   apiCall="com.example.email.service.KafkaConsumer"
>   stacktrace="java.lang.Exception: Invalid to-email-address     at
>   com.example.email.service.KafkaConsumer.handleMessages(KafkaConsumer.java:84)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:181)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:445)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:394)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:181)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
>     at
>   org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:203)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$300(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:70)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:387)
>     at
>   org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:364)
>     at
>   org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1071)
>     at
>   org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1051)
>     at
>   org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:998)
>     at
>   org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:866)
>     at
>   org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:724)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)  " message="Time taken to
>   process message is 2265ms.For orderId = 6207168, templateName =
>   TERMS_CONDITIONS, sessionId = 77337650, storeId = 1892. errorMessage =
>   {}"

I suspect that the wrapper method might be the culprit, since I am passing the logger instance from the class where the exception occurred to the wrapper methods. I'm not sure though. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: please share values for `${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}`, `${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}` and a `catch` block of any piece of a code where any log method of the `LoggingUtil` is invoking

Comment: I am including base.xml in my logback.xml which in turn includes the default.xml from Spring framework. Which can be found at : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml

Comment: Here is a code snippet for the invocation of LoggingUtil method.
`try {
/*Process request - happy path */
LoggingUtil.logInfo(responseMessage, emailRequest, LOGGER);
} catch(Exception e) {
responseMessage = "Error occurred while processing message.";
LoggingUtil.logError(responseMessage, emailRequest, e, LOGGER);
}`

Comment: Value for console and file patthern:

`<property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN:-%clr(%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"/>
 <property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="${FILE_LOG_PATTERN:-%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN:-yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} ${PID:- } --- [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}"/>`

Comment: I've wasted enough time trying to find out the problem but i didn't( sorry. Just try to exclude all third party factors like your wrapper, probably some extra configs on the server size and so on. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) - there are some extra info how to debug. Anyway let me know if you'll find out the reason of the problem!